# How we can use two headers with "and" logical in envoy proxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, envoyproxy

Use Case: I need to send a request to the server (cluster) after matching **two headers** with "AND" logic.

Is this possible in Envoy? if yes please help with syntax or solution-

my envoy configmap looks like-

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-envoy-conf
data:
  envoy.yaml: |
    static_resources:
      listeners:

      - address:
          socket_address:
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 443
        traffic_direction: OUTBOUND

        filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              codec_type: AUTO
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: https
                  domains:
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                      headers:

                      - name: x-envoy-original-dst-host
                        string_match:
                          suffix: ": 10004"

                      - name: app
                        exact_match: "ms-example-server"

                      and_match: true
                    
                    route:
                      cluster: destination_cluster
                  

              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                

          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain:
                      filename: "/etc/ssl/envoy/tls.crt"
                    private_key:
                      filename: "/etc/ssl/envoy/tls.key"
         

      # Setup the Original Destination cluster
      clusters:

      - name: destination_cluster
        .....
```

Is it possible to match headers based on AND logic and send to the desired cluster in an envoy?

Comment: You can use [lua filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter) for performing validation on your headers using Lua script. This **`Lua script`** will be triggered at request and response stage and helps you perform all types of validations. Go through these [examples](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/e665d4292d40f05f6e40460a8424855bf1e277fc/examples/lua) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
and_match:
      rules:
        - http_request_headers_match:
            headers:
              - name: foo
                string_match:
                  exact: bar
        - http_response_headers_match:
            headers:
              - name: bar
                string_match:
                  exact: baz
```

Comment: Can we use and_match with virtual_hosts ? the above solution is not working for my use case.

Comment: made some changes in above example code, please check and help